# How can I debug dist/ is not generating on Docker Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-cloud

I’m trying to **automate** build on **dockercloud** to build a docker container for my front-end.

[image]

---

## I have

**web.dockerfile**

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:9.3.0-alpine as builder

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i
RUN mkdir /web
RUN cp -R ./node_modules ./web

WORKDIR /web

COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.8-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html/

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

USER nginx
```

as you see I already did this line :

> RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer

Which it should generate the `dist/` folder for me.

---

## I got

This long logs in my docker-cloud

[image]

What I don't understand is, it is working fine, when I used that Dockerfile locally.

Should I look into my webpack settings or my Dockerfile syntax ?

Comment: Maybe `COPY --from=builder /web/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/` ? Although I'm not sure how it's working locally without the `--from`

Comment: You probably have a `dist/` folder locally for dev, then that's what is being copied in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--from` argument to [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) to set the source location to a previous build stage.

```
COPY --from=builder /web/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

For your local build you probably have a `dist/` folder for your local development which is then included in the build context sent to Docker. The local copy is what ends up in the image.

Comment: will attempt this now. Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: My build taking so long to build. 99% of latency cause my `RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer` do u have any suggestions for me ? Is there another way that I can achieve what I am trying to do, without build my npm build inside my container ?

Comment: No sorry, I did see your other question but I've not attempted an angular build in Docker so don't have any tricks up my sleeve.